# submitHandler - Jquery Validate and Magento

Tags: jquery, validation, magento

For some reason I cannot get this to submit at all in magento. The form validates just fine. Its just it seems like once its validated it doesnt want to do anything.

```
    $j('#send').click(function(){
    var form = $j('#share_email_submit');
    form.validate({
        submitHandler: function(){
            var data = $j(form).serialize();
            alert(data);
            $j.post('catdog.php', data);
        }
    }).form();
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the validate method of the validator magento object.

> validator.validate()

It returns boolean false if magento validation failed otherwise true.

To activate the magento validation, you should have set somewhere in your code something as

> var validate_form = new VarienForm('form_id',true);

It seems that in your code '`share_email_submit`' should be the above '`form_id`'

Then you can turn the code you posted into something like

```
$j('#send').click(function()
{
    if (validate_form.validator.validate())
    {
        var form = $j('#share_email_submit');
        var data = $j(form).serialize();
        console.log(data);
        $j.post('catdog.php', data);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Validation Failed');
    }
    return false;
});
```